# Animation in OpenGL using Assimp

Tags: opengl, animation, assimp

I've recently found out that there is a library called "Assimp" for importing models that can be rendering animations in c++ opengl, and now I try to figure out what I have to do, in order to load a textured model and draw it...

1) What format is recommended to export animations from Blender?

2) I have a basic mesh class already, drawing a model. What would I need to modify to support animation?

My data struct:

```
struct ObjectData {
    vector <glm::vec3> vertices, normals, colors;
    vector <glm::vec2> texCoords;
    vector <GLuint> vIndices, uIndices, nIndices;
    vector <Material*> materials;
    glm::vec3 size, center;
};
```

My mesh VBO and draw:

```
void Mesh::draw() {
    if (initialized) {
        shader->enable(true);

        if (texture != NULL) {
            texture->enable(true);
        }

        //Tell OpenGL which array to use
        glBindVertexArray(arrayObject);

        glDrawElements(renderMode, object->vIndices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glBindVertexArray(NULL);
        shader->enable(false);

        if (texture != NULL) {
            texture->enable(false);
        }
    }
}

void Mesh::updateVBO() {
    if (!initialized) {
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &arrayObject);
    }

    //Tell OpenGL which vertex array to use from now
    glBindVertexArray(arrayObject);

    if (!initialized) {
        glGenBuffers(VBO_COUNT, buffers);
        initialized = true;
    }

    //Set buffer data
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[VBO_VERTEX]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * object->vertices.size(), &object->vertices.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //Set shader attribute data
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VBO_VERTEX);
    glVertexAttribPointer(VBO_VERTEX, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, NULL, NULL);

    if (object->colors.size()) {
        //Set buffer data
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[VBO_COLOR]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * object->colors.size(), &object->colors.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        //Set shader attribute data
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(VBO_COLOR);
        glVertexAttribPointer(VBO_COLOR, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, NULL, NULL);
    }

    if (object->texCoords.size()) {
        //Set buffer data
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[VBO_TEXCORD]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec2) * object->texCoords.size(), &object->texCoords.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        //Set shader attribute data
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(VBO_TEXCORD);
        glVertexAttribPointer(VBO_TEXCORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, NULL, NULL);
    }

    if (object->normals.size()) {
        //Set buffer data
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[VBO_NORMAL]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * object->normals.size(), &object->normals.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        //Set shader attribute data
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(VBO_NORMAL);
        glVertexAttribPointer(VBO_NORMAL, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, NULL, NULL);
    }

    //Set buffer data
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[VBO_INDEX]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLuint) * object->vIndices.size(), &object->vIndices.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //Unbind vertex array
    glBindVertexArray(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The 'open asset import library' has a [model viewer](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/main_viewer.html) where you can preview the models with all aclaimed supported formats (including animations). I would suggest exporting your animations, to a variety of formats and see if any of them give you wrong results (i.e. render artifacts) and conclude your own awnser. Personally, I had the most success with Collada (.dae) although I used 3ds Max.

To support the animation itself (presumable skeletal): interpolate the animation data (aiNodeAnim) between the key-frames;  you need to calculate the bone matrices from the interpolated animation data (create a matrix out of position/rotation etc); calculate the 'animated' vertices by transforming the 'vertices' (aiMesh/aiBone) with the bone matrices that influence them; weight all of the 'animated vertices' and sum them together; render the newly vertices. And this a basic high level overview of animations.

There are tutorials and books that can go deeper into the subject. For example [ogldev's tutorial 38](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html), [Jason Gregory's Game Engine Architechture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814135) has dedicated animation chapter. You can take a look at the source code of assimps model viewer.

Comment: I found some issues exporting animations from Blender as COLLADA and importing with Assimp (bone rotations looked incorrect). As these issues were present when I reimported the same file into Blender, I think they were bugs in the exporter.